# how to store bearer token in cookies in react js frontend

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, bearer-token

I am using React JS for the front-end part of my code. I want to store the bearer token in cookies and then return the bearer token in the content field when the API is called successfully. As I haven't used cookies earlier so want to know how I can accomplish this task. Also the back-end part is not done by me.
Following is the code in which I am calling the API

```
onSubmitSignup = () => {
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://35.154.16.105:8080/signup/checkMobile',{
        method:'post',
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            mobile:this.state.mobile
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
        if(data.statusCode === '2000'){
            localStorage.setItem('mobile',this.state.mobile);
            // this.props.loadNewUser(this.state.mobile);
            this.props.onRouteChange('otp','nonav');
        }
    })
    // this.props.onRouteChange('otp','nonav');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, on this line:

```
if(data.statusCode === '2000'){
```

Are you sure the status code shouldn't be 200 and not 2000.

Secondly, there are packages for managing cookies. One that springs to mind is:

[Link to GitHub "Universal Cookie" repo](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie)

However you can use vanilla js to manage cookies, more info can be found on the Mozilla website:

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

When you make that initial API call, within the data returned, I assume the Bearer token is returned too. Initialise the cookie there like so:

```
document.cookie = "Bearer=example-bearer-token;"
```

When you need access to the cookie at a later date, you can just use the following code:

```
const cookieValue = document.cookie
  .split('; ')
  .find(row => row.startsWith('Bearer'))
  .split('=')[1];
```

And then forward the bearer with the next call.

### Edit

Set the cookie bearer token like this:

```
document.cookie = "Bearer=example-bearer-token;"
```

Get the cookie bearer token like this:

```
const cookieValue = document.cookie
.split('; ')
.find(row => row.startsWith('Bearer'))
.split('=')[1];
```

A cookie is made up of key/value pairs separated by a semi-colon. Therefore the above code to get the "Bearer" value, firstly gets the cookie, splits it into its key/value pairs, finds the row that has a key of "Bearer" and splits that row to attain the Bearer token.

In your comment you say the dev team said the bearer will be in the "content". In your ajax request you already have access to that content through data. You need to debug that request to find out what it is coming back as. I assume you just need to grab the token from the returned data inside of the "If" block where you check for your statusCode.

It will be something like:

```
document.cookie = "Bearer=" + data.bearer;
```

However, I don't have the shape of your data so you can only work that final part out yourself.

Comment: I was informed by the back-end team that the status code will be 2000 on successful validation. And the bearer token will be returned in the "content" field when successfully validated. Now I want to know that how I can store the token in cookies in front-end part (ReactJS). Also can you please explain me that how I will get this Bearer=example-bearer-token;

Comment: Edited my answer. See at the bottom under sub-heading "Edit".

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer, could you mark it as accepted please. Thanks.